# Adding Azure key vault task in pipeline (AKS)

Tags: azure-keyvault

I added Azure key vault task in pipeline.
-task:azurekeyvault
inputs:
azureSubscription:""
KeyVaultName:""
SecretsFilter:*
RunAsPreJob:false
In yaml the following lines appeared on the top of yaml file and when trying to run it shows error
ENCOUNTERED ERROR WHILE PARSING PIPELINE YAML:

Comment: You need ADO tag, not Key Vault.

Comment: Before adding key vault task in pipeline (AKS)
trigger:
-master
resources:
-repo:self
variables:
-------
stages:
-template:build.yml
parameters:
-template:deploy.yml 
parameters:
environment:test
-template:deploy.yml
parameters:
environment:dev
After adding key vault aks in pipeline 
This code snippets gets included in random place:
-task:azurekeyvault
    inputs:
        subscription:''
        KeyVaultName:''
        SecretsFilter:*
        RunAsPreJob:false
And hence getting the above error 
Where exactly this task snippet should be added in azure-pipeline.yml file.